# How do I embed non-controllable videos in my react-native application

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, video, youtube

I'm working on a Node.js application, with React Native for the UI. So basically I want to embed videos in the application. I don't want to store the videos myself, so I want to use YouTube or some other free video platform to upload the video, and then I want to play it in the application. I've tried to use both react-native-video and react-native-youtube but it didn't work.

Then I tried to use WebView and I managed to make it work, in the sense that i could play the YouTube video, but the issues are that there is a YouTube brand in the video, and it goes full screen when you cLick on the video and you can basically control the video like you can in YouTube (play, pause, move forward, subtitles, etc.). All of this should not even be possible. I'm only, solely interested in the video playing in a loop. no sound, no full screen mode, not clickable, no buttons, no brand, nothing.. Almost as if it was a gif image...

How do I achieve this?

This is what I've tried:

```
{restaurantData.hasVideo ? (
    <WebView
        style={{ width: '100%', height: 300 }}
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        source={{
            html: `
                <html>
                <body style="margin:0px;padding:0px;overflow:hidden">
                    <iframe
                        style="width:100%;height:100%"
                        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/${restaurantData.videoId}?autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=${restaurantData.videoId}&mute=1"
                        frameborder="0"
                        allow="autoplay; loop; accelerometer; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                        allowfullscreen="false"
                    ></iframe>
                </body>
                </html>
            `,
        }}
    />
) : (
    // Render image if hasVideo is false
    <Image
        source={{ uri: restaurantData.image }}
        style={{ width: '100%', height: 300, resizeMode: 'cover' }}
    />
)}
```